# Binding multiple source an element's dependency properties in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

Is it possible to bind multiple source to an element's dependecy properties?

In my case, I have a combobox control its ItemSource property filled by a viewmodel, however the Text property is binded to a model which is used by an ItemsControl.

Thank you.

xaml snippet:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumType}" Value="6">
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>                
            <ComboBox    
                x:Name="ListOfItems"  
                IsDropDownOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
                IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
                IsReadOnly="False"
                IsEditable="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredSource,  Source={StaticResource ItemsVM} ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
                Text="{Binding   Path=Result, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                 
                DisplayMemberPath="{Binding  Path=Item.Name,  Source={StaticResource ItemsVM}}" >                 

                <ComboBox.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBoxBase.TextChanged">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames   Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsDropDownOpen">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ComboBox.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: The answer is yes. Not sure what you'd do with that or what problem you're trying to resolve but yes you can multibind if it's one property or use various approaches such as relativesource to get to a different viewmodel than the datacontext. You should edit your question so it's clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can set the `Source` of each binding. `DisplayMemberPath`should be set to a `string` by the way: `DisplayMemberPath="Name"`.

Comment: @Andy thank you, and that means an elements whole properties can be  binded with different sources or diffrent viewmodels. I agree that sounds a little bit weird , i have a legacy code that is very odd, so refactoring takes long time, i am searching a way.

Comment: Say you had a datagrid with a comboboxcolumn in it then your datacontext of each row is the item presented from itemssource to it - the row viewmodel. Yet you often will have a collection of options all rows will use. So it makes sense rather than being weird. Still not sure what you're asking here. But Magnus is correct and one problem you have there is any of those properties ending "path" on a combo should be a string representing the path to the property - often just a property name.

Comment: @mm8 since Item is my model it has Name propety, thanks

Comment: @Nazim: Then it should be `Item.Name` but still not a binding.

Comment: @mm8  I just try to create a datacontext for just combobox's ıtemsource and displaymemeberpath property. the other properties wil bind its itemcontrol's datacontext

Comment: @Nazim: The `DisplayMemberPath` has no `DataContext`. It just specifies the name of a property. Again, it makes no sense to bind to this property.

Comment: @mm8 yes, you are right, I see now my mistake, Displaymemberpath is just a property, it has no relationship with binding just because it takes its content from ıtemssources elements, ın order to protect data consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Source` of each binding like you are currently doing for the `ItemsSource` property:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredSource, Source={StaticResource ItemsVM}}"
```

If you don't do this, the framework will look for the `FilteredSource` property in the current `DataContext` of the `ComboBox`.

By the way, the `DisplayMemberPath` property should be set to a `string` that specifies the name of a property of an item in the `ItemsSource`:

```
DisplayMemberPath="Name"
```

You should not bind to this property.

It also makes no sense to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property for an `ItemsSource` binding to `PropertyChanged`, or set the `Mode` to `TwoWay`, since the control won't set the source property.

Comment: if I dont  bind 'DisplayMemberPath' here it directly takes current 'DataContext' which has no Name Property. Is there a way to bind 'ItemsSource' and 'DisplayMemberPath' to ItemVM, thanks

Comment: No. `DisplayMemberPath` always refers to a property of an item in the current `ItemsSource`.